# how to change partitions on another computer

Tags: 16.04

I have another computer with Mythbuntu on it. I need to change the size of the boot partition on it because I need to upgrade all the software, but I can't do it with his own partition manager.
I thought it could be done by connecting the PC to my own and using mine to change the other.  Is there a way to use the computer like an external hard disk ?

Comment: The best way to do that would be to remove the other hard disk from the pc you need to change and bring to to yours in a USB enclosure

Answer (score 0):

There are two practical ways to do what you want.  First is to dismount the hard disk and connect it to another computer, then use the partition management tools on that system to change the partition size.  This *shouldn't* change the UUIDs, but be aware that if it does, your Mythbuntu system likely won't boot afterward.

The other way is to boot the Mythbuntu machine with a Live USB or DVD and use the Live system's tools to change your partitions.  This is likely slower (Live systems tend to be pretty pokey), but doesn't require you to have another computer that can read your Ubuntu partitions (which most Windows systems, for instance, cannot).

Comment: additionally, if you ran the live system from RAM, speed difference could be negligible.

Comment: If the system has enough RAM to do so (I think it requires 4 GB these days), I believe that's automatic, at least with Ubuntu Live media.  Of course, that won't help much if you run something that needs lots of RAM to work -- like partition move/resize operations...

Comment: I cannot remove a live stick when running. It crashes with squashfs errors

Comment: @MarkYisri Normally, when running Live from RAM, you don't remove the thumb drive -- the core of the OS loads into a RAMdisk, but some less used external commands will remain on the USB or DVD, and need to be available to load if needed.  If you don't have enough RAM, the entire OS is on the Live media, so the system can't run if you remove it (that's why Live is often a bit slow -- the USB port is a lot slower than SATA or IDE interface).

Comment: exactly, so it isn't perfectly RAM based

Comment: however, USB 3.0 is as fast as SATA I believe

Comment: @MarkYisri Even if the whole OS is in RAM (as when I've run antiX from Live on a 4 GB RAM system -- HDD installation will fit in 4 GB), the system won't unmount the USB, so in theory it can write back changes that need to be saved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47872/discussion-between-mark-yisri-and-zeiss-ikon).